# How to reduce the width of a plot display in Python Dash?

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

This is my code for a callback function as a part of a bigger code using the Dash package.

```
@app.callback(
    Output("graph-container", "children"),
    Input("type-dropdown", "value"),
)
def update_graph(serial_number):
    
    serial_data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Enigma/data.csv")
    # Taking subset
    serial_data = serial_data[serial_data["serial_num"] == serial_number]

    # Plot the data
    fig = px.scatter(serial_data, x="date_time", y="voltage")
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=serial_data["date_time"], 
            y=serial_data["voltage"], 
            mode="markers",
            marker=dict(
                color=np.where(serial_data["after_red"], "orange", np.where(serial_data["voltage"] < 2.1, "red", "blue")),
                size=8
            )
        )
    )  
    
    # Set the x-axis range
    x_range = [np.min(serial_data["date_time"]), np.max(serial_data["date_time"])]
    
    # Set the x-axis range for the scatter plot and the line plot
    fig.update_xaxes(range=x_range)

    # Get the minimum and maximum y-axis values with a gap before the lowest value
    y_min = np.floor(serial_data["voltage"].min()) - 0.01
    
    fig.update_layout(
        title={
            'text': "Voltage Variation",
            'y':0.98,
            'x':0.5,
            'xanchor': 'center',
            'yanchor': 'top'
        },
        xaxis_title="Time", 
        yaxis_title="Voltage", 
        showlegend=False,
        # Set the y-axis range with a gap before the lowest value
        yaxis_range=[y_min, None],
        # Add some margin to the bottom of the plot
        margin=dict(l=50, r=50, b=50, t=50, pad=20),
        height=500
    )
    
    # Add a horizontal line at y = 2.1
    fig.add_shape(
        type="line",
        x0=serial_data["date_time"].min(),
        x1=serial_data["date_time"].max(),
        y0=2.100,
        y1=2.100,
        line=dict(color="black", dash="dot")
    )
    
    return html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Graph(
                id="first-graph",
                figure=fig
            )
        ],
        style={"width": "100%"},
    )
```

The issue is that whenever I include the following portion of the code (as shown above) for setting up the x-axis range, my plot gets chopped-off at the right extreme.

```
    # Set the x-axis range
    x_range = [np.min(serial_data["date_time"]), np.max(serial_data["date_time"])]
    
    # Set the x-axis range for the scatter plot and the line plot
    fig.update_xaxes(range=x_range)
```

The chopped-off plot:
[image]

But when I don't include this portion of the code, the complete plot gets displayed:
[image]

Can anyone please help to get the complete plot displayed even after including the portion of the code for setting up the x-axis range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want some padding on either side of the xaxis range. By default plotly sets the axis range to be `[min - padding, max + padding]` where `padding = (max-min)/16`.

So if you want a range that's a little bit closer to your min and max date time, you could try making the padding less than the default:

```
x_min, x_max = min(serial_data["date_time"]), max(serial_data["date_time"])
padding = (x_max - x_min) / 32
x_range = [x_min - padding, x_max + padding]

fig.update_xaxes(range=x_range)
```